# PHP with JSON converted to classic ASP

Tags: javascript, php, json, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on the login part of an android app. There is a PHP page that uses JSON to get the input from the app and queries it to the SQL database and returns if the login is succesful or not.

Now, my boss doesn't want a PHP page and it has to be ASP.

How can I convert the PHP page to ASP page that uses vbscript/javascript?

I found http://www.aspjson.com/ 
Not sure how to convert the json_encode

PHP page code:

```
 <?php mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 
$db= mysql_select_db("database"); 
$androidID=$_POST["androidID"]; 
$username=$_POST["username"]; 
if (!empty($_POST)) { 
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['androidID'])) { 
// Create some data that will be the JSON response 
$response["success"] = 0; 
$response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty ."; 

//die is used to kill the page, will not let the code below to be executed. It will also
//display the parameter, that is the json data which our android application will parse to be 
//shown to the users 
die(json_encode($response)); 
} 
$query = " SELECT id, username, aid FROM login WHERE username = '$username'and aid='$androidID'"; 
$sql1=mysql_query($query); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1); 
if (!empty($row)) { $response["success"] = 1; 
$response["message"] = "You have been sucessfully login"; 
die(json_encode($response)); 
} 
else{ 
$response["success"] = 0; $response["message"] = "invalid username or password "; 
die(json_encode($response)); 
}
} 
else{ $response["success"] = 0; 
$response["message"] = " One or both of the fields are empty "; 
die(json_encode($response)); 
} 

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP expert, but I think that `die()` returns the string passed to it back to the client and stops the script.

I think the equivalent ASP would be

```
response.write json_encode(responseObject)
response.end
```

So then the question is how to write `json_encode`.

Personally, given this exact example, I would simplify the task by hand-coding the JSON response:

```
response.write "{success:1, message:""You have been successfully login""}"
response.end
```

This avoids the necessity of figuring out how to implement a general-purpose JSON encoding method to do this very simple thing. You could make it slightly more general-purpose by writing a method that takes a success code and a message string and returns a JSON string if you want.